# Localizable を無効にしたのにビルド時に `***.ja-JP.resx` リソースファイルを参照しようとする

Tags: c#, visual-studio, localization

Visual Studio C# で開発しているアプリケーションの Form で、`Localizable=true` にしていたのですが、ローカライズ対応不要ということがわかり、このプロパティを `false` へ変更しました。

変更後も作成済の `*.jp-JP.resx` / `*.ja.resx` のようなリソースファイルが残っており、削除するとビルドエラーとなります。

> Resouce file *****.ja-JP.resx cannot be found.

このエラーを回避し、プロジェクトが参照しないようにする方法をご教示ください。

Comment: 一度プロジェクトをクリーンしてからビルドしても同じ状況ですか？ また、csprojファイル内でリソースファイルに関する記述が残っていないでしょうか？

Comment: 別の方からもご指摘いただいたように、`*Form.cs`配下にリソースファイルが残っていたようです。ご回答ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

おそらくソリューションエクスプローラー内の、Propertiesツリーの中に該当ファイルの参照が見つかります。
それをプロジェクトから削除します。

もっとも汎用的な対処方法は、Subversionなどのソース管理システムを利用して、プロジェクトファイル（XXX.csproj）にどのような変更が起こったかを確認し、その変更を望む形に取り消すことだと思います。

Comment: Properties配下のリソースファイルは`Resouces.resx`のみで、
他のリソースファイルは追加されていませんでした。  

また、Subversionを使用しているのですが、`Localizable=true`によるファイル増減は`*.jp.resx` / `*.jp-JP.resx`が追加になったのみです（*はフォーム名）。  

ソリューションのプロパティにあるリソース定義も確認したのですが、何も追加されていませんでした。

Comment: 手元の2012で、同様の手順を行ってみたのですがそもそも *.jp-JP.resx / *.ja.resx が追加されませんでした...  
Subversionを使用しているなら、Form1.Designer.cs や Form1.resx の方も見ると何か違いがあるかもしれません。  
差分が出ない形で、ビルドエラーが出ない状態から出る状態になることは無いでしょうから、バージョン管理していないファイルを削除すると直る可能性もありますね。

Comment: 私の環境は2008なのですが、ご指摘のように`*Form.cs`配下に`*.jp.resx`が生成されていました。ここから削除して問題なくビルド時に参照されず、実ファイルも削除されることを確認しました。どうもありがとうございました。ちゃんと確認すれば分かることですね、気を付けます。。